# android Bluetooth-LowEnergy not stable connection

Tags: android, bluetooth-lowenergy, android-bluetooth, ios-bluetooth

I am developing a BLE based android app in which my app will send data to all the paired devices that may be IOS/Android based.My app is successfully getting connected with and sending data to multiple connected devices (one at a time), but the issue i am facing is my device (containing my app) starts connecting and disconnecting continuously with other devices, the issue is very strange and i cannot figure it out.Any idea whats going on with it?

Thank you.

Comment: Did you try to debug your app, so you can check whether it is your central- or peripheral device that terminates the connection ?

Comment: Yeah i have checked many devices when i connected and paired with other than my devices too, same behaviour occurs. Still stuck there.

Comment: If you can [get the hcidump btsnoop file from Android](https://www.nowsecure.com/blog/2014/02/07/bluetooth-packet-capture-android/), look for the Disconnect Complete event (wireshark filter: bthci_evt.code == 0x05). Look at the Reason field within the HCI Disconnect Complete event. It lists the reason for termination e.g. 0x13 Remote User Terminated Connection, 0x16 Connection Terminated By Local Host, 0x05 Connection Timeout, etc. (See Bluetooth 4.0, Vol 2, Part D Error Codes). What is the reason for termination?

Comment: For multiple connections you could try to create multiple objects for those connections, instead of channelling them all through one? Or is this how you implemented it originally? Did you find the answer eventually? If so, post it back here! (Since this is a somewhat older question)